# Does Microsoft Virtual Machine Manager Support Storing VHDs on File Server Share?

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, virtual-machines, network-share

I have a Hyper-V server running perfectly fine with the VHDs placed on a separate file server shared folder. Now when I install MS Virtual Machine Manager and add the host machine to VMM, it says "Unsupported Configuration" next to each of the Virtual Machines, except one which has its VHD located on the same Hyper-V host server.

I found this discussion: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/virtualmachingmgrhyperv/thread/676e134f-beef-451a-b612-7c9254023b99/

Does this mean, I cannot use Virtual Machine Manager with VHDs on a shared drive? Does anyone have experience with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Are you mapping the file share as a local drive?  If not, I would at least give that a shot.

Comment: It doesn't work either way: folder share or mapped drive.